# Android - Accessing Array in multiple activities

Tags: java, android, arrays, public

Just a real quick question. I've defined an array in one activity and I'm trying to access it in another one. I was planing to extend it as so:

```
public class MyChallenges extends Main {
```

But I need to extend 'ListActivity' to get my code to work, as I am using a custom listview, so I can't extend two activities. As shown:

```
public class MyChallenges extends ListActivity {
```

Is there any other way, apart from extending the main activity? This is the array I'm trying to access for read and write:

```
public String[][] arr = new String[2][6];
```

So, in short, how can I access the array 'arr' from another class? Thanks guys!

Comment: sort of unclear, do you want to access the contents of an array in one Activity in another, or is this a question about inheritance - having access to the variable from a subclass? You don't extend ListActivity unless you mean it..

Comment: I just need to access the contents of the array in a different activity from the one it was defined

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make a class that contains the array, and reference that class from your activities. For example:

```
public class ArrayOfStuff
{
    public static String[][] arr = new String[2][6];
}
```

Then, to modify the array, use something like `ArrayOfStuff.arr[1][1] = "foo";`

Happy coding!

Comment: You are welcome, be sure to upvote to help me out. I had a similar issue with an android app, and this worked very well.

Answer (score 1):

The  element of a resources file can only be used for single dimension arrays. In other words, everything between  and  is considered to be a single string.

If you want to store data in the way you describe (effectively pseudo-XML), you'll need to get the items as a single String[] using getStringArray(...) and parse the  and  elements yourself.

Personally I'd possibly go with a de-limited format such as...

Bahrain,12345
...then just use split(...).

Alternatively, define each  as a JSONObject such as... and treat this array as JSON object and use JSON method for get value for element...

{name:Bahrain,codes:12345}

->simply create string array at res/values/strings.xml:
->after u can access this string array in whole application...